# Why is line continuation is indented with 12 spaces in vimscript?

Tags: indentation

```
let b:some = {
            \ 'some',
            \ 'array',
}
```

This makes code ugly IMHO, how can I change that and should I change that? Is that some coding style or something in vimscript?

Also, is there a plugin that would (I think I had one, but I don't know which one) would expand `<CR>` like delimitMate with inserting appropriate number of spaces and `\`?

Comment: `:h ft-vim-indent`

Answer (score 8):

You can change the amount of that indentation by setting the variable `g:vim_indent_cont`, e.g.,

```
:let g:vim_indent_cont = &sw
```

See

```
:help ft-vim-indent
```

Comment: Christian Brabandt: I didn't see your comment til just now.